# WCF not accessible from web

Tags: c#, wcf

I have imported an a wcf service and it is accessible from local host but when I use my public ip address i am unable to reach it.

This is the contents of my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"
                     targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <extensions>
            <bindingExtensions>
                <add name="clearUsernameBinding"
                     type="WebServices20.BindingExtenions.ClearUsernameCollectionElement, ClearUsernameBinding" />
            </bindingExtensions>
            <!-- Add the inspector attribute as a behavior for displaying SOAP XML packets -->
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="consoleOutputBehavior"
                     type="WcfService1.ConsoleOutputBehaviorExtensionElement, WcfService1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <bindings>
            <clearUsernameBinding>
                <binding name="myClearUsernameBinding"
                         messageVersion="Soap12" />
            </clearUsernameBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <!-- Add the inspector behavior -->
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="inspectorBehavior">
                    <consoleOutputBehavior />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HelloWorldServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.CustomUserNameValidator, WcfService1" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="HelloWorldServiceBehavior"
                     name="WcfService1.HelloWorldService">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="clearUsernameBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="myClearUsernameBinding"
                          contract="WcfService1.IHelloWorldService" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have a console app that is able to communicate with it but ONLY with localhost.

This is how I am able to get to it. It is running on port 14946 and have port forwarded that port to the computer that has the service running. It is hosted on IIS.

http://localhost:14946/HelloWorldService.svc?singleWsd

If I use : {publicIP}:14946/HelloWorldService.svc?singleWsd 
I get a 500 internal error which means its a configuration issue but I can't seem to pinpoint what the problem is.

EDIT: I am now receiving this error.

The type 'WcfService1.HelloWorldService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found. I am able to get to it over the web now but receiving this error now. In order to fix the previous error I had to: 1.) Go to add remove features 2.) Expand MS .NET Framework 3.) Flip on both HTTP and Non-HTTP activation for WCF

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you properly hosted it in IIS you can just remove the port in endpoint and access it directly, something like this: `( add virtual application if necessary )`

```
http://<public ip>/HelloWorldService.svc?singleWsd
```

It is working in your localhost because it was hosted in IIS Express upon debug mode and automatically assigned that port.

Comment: I have tried the above but still not able to reach it from the web. It must be a configuration problem but I can't seem to pinpoint it

Comment: Do you have virtual directory in your IIS? How did you host your service in IIS?

Comment: I just right clicked sites and added a site. For bindings I just bound it to my machines private ip and I have port forwarded that port to this computer.

Comment: So you did not used the Default Web Site then and add application.. Try to add your application in Default Web Site.. by Right clicking Default Web Site -> Add Application -> put your alias and point the directory where your service resides.. That is much easier. And BTW, the last word in your endpoint should be singleWsdl not singleWsd.

Comment: If you want to pursue the one you created site you need to set it as web site default.

Comment: Sorry still unable to get to it if I try to get to it from the web I get a 400 http error.

Comment: try this first : by right clicking Default Web Site -> Add Application -> put your alias and point the directory where your service resides and let talk the rest after this..

Comment: Cool so i set my alias as 'soap' and have added the site. Right now it is set to use port 80 however the service is running on 14946 but i might be getting ahead of myself.

Comment: If you want port 14946 : Click Default Web Site again and at the right side you can see Bindings and add your port.

Comment: If I "Add Web Site" i can adjust the binding but not if i do Add Application.

Comment: Click Default Web Site->Bindings (located in right side)->Add

Comment: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map. This is the error I get but I can at least get to it from the web but its just the main screen once I specify my svc file it throws this error.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas that could be causing this?

Comment: The type 'WcfService1.HelloWorldService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found.

I am able to get to it over the web now but receiving this error now.

In order to fix the previous error I had to:

1.) Go to add remove features
2.) Expand MS .NET Framework
3.) Flip on both HTTP and Non-HTTP activation for WCF